# Warning: Error in aggregate.data.frame: arguments must have same length Stack trace (innermost first)

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, sqldf

I have an r assignment. I am making an interactive plot for a sports team and when I try to calculate the average of the scored goals I keep getting the same error (Error in aggregate.data.frame: arguments must have same length
Stack trace (innermost first)). i tried making the tp variable as data frame and I tried using the tapply function instead of the aggregate but I kept getting the same error. 
this is my UI part

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotrix)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column ( width = 3,

         h4(span(tagList(icon("filter")), "Select team")),
         selectizeInput('team', "", choices = shots$TeamName, selected = TRUE),
         br(),

         h4(span(tagList(icon("filter")), "Select season")),
         selectizeInput('season', "", choices = shots$SeasonNr, selected = TRUE),
         br()
)),

plotlyOudataut("pos1")
)
```

and my server part is:

```
server <- function(input,oudataut, session){  

  observeEvent(c(input$team), {
team1 <- input$team
SeasonTx <- input$season
tp <- sqldf(sprintf("select Fullname,  Percentage, ShotType, ShotsMade, ShotsNumber, TrainingDate, Position from shots where TeamName is '%s'", team1, "AND SeasonText is '%s'", SeasonTx))

percentageColumn<- aggregate(tp[,4:5], list(tp$TeamName, tp$Position), sum)
    percentageColumn$average <- ((percentageColumn$ShotsMade/percentageColumn$ShotsNumber)*100)
    colnames(percentageColumn) <- c("Team", "Position", "ShotsMade", "ShotsNumber", "Average")
  oudataut$pos1 <-renderPlotly({
plot_ly(x = ~percentageColumn$Position, y = ~percentageColumn$Average, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')%>%
  layout(title = 'The Average score of the whole team per position',
         xaxis = list(title = 'position',dtick=1),
         yaxis = list (title = 'Percentage'),xasis=position)
 }]
 })}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

can anyone see the mistake ?
thanks in advance

Comment: it seems `TeamName` is missing in your `select` and therefore `tp$TeamName` would be `NULL`?

Comment: i adjusted the code a little by adding the team sky like this.    tp <- sqldf(sprintf("select Fullname,  Percentage, ShotType, ShotsMade, ShotsNumber, TrainingDate, Position, Team_skey from shots where Team_skey is '%s'", team1, "AND SeasonText is '%s'", SeasonTx)). but now i get a different error ("Warning: Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 0 rows, data has 15") which is confusing to me because of the 0 rows. do you know why this happened?

Comment: @RolandASc i solved this problem by adjusting a couple things in the server part. i adjusted the select statement, aggregate function and added adataframe to bind it with the aggregate function.